# Spring @RefreshScope - Reload/Refresh bean conditionally

Tags: spring-cloud

I am using @RefreshScope in @Configuration classes to annotate beans which can be reloaded using the /actuator/refresh end point. In case there is any change in application.properties, on posting /actuator/refresh, it marks the bean marked with @RefreshScope for reload so the next time it is accessed, bean will be reloaded.

Is there any way of configuring @RefreshScope so that bean is refreshed only under certain circumstances and not for every change in application.properties? For eg: based on the value of a property flag in application.properties

Regards,
Jacob